# MySQL subquery will not work

Tags: mysql

I have problems with subquerys.
In phpMyAdmin when I enter this:

```
SELECT companys.id 
  FROM companys 
  JOIN users 
    ON users.company = companys.id 
 WHERE users.id = '$LOGGED_IN_USER'
```

I get number 1 returned. That is correct.

And then I tested:

```
UPDATE companys 
   SET companys.signature = '$SIGNATURE' 
 WHERE companys.id = 1
```

That also works, it updates the value with $SIGNATURE where companys.id = 1. So far so good. Now to the problem. The problem appears when I combine those two:

```
UPDATE companys 
   SET companys.signature = '$SIGNATURE' 
 WHERE companys.id = ( SELECT companys.id 
                         FROM companys 
                         JOIN users 
                           ON users.company = companys.id 
                        WHERE users.id = '$LOGGED_IN_USER')
```

The DB never gets updated. It is like the inner select doesn't work suddenly for some reason.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: This is done in context of PHP, it would seem. And if you don't see an error it is because you aren't logging/displaying errors or even checking for them.  MysQL probably disallows this query because you are trying to modify the `companys` table while also using it in the `WHERE` clause. That can't be done without a join.

Comment: You need to check the relevant error method for the API you're using `mysql_error(), mysqli_error(), `PDO::errorInfo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the update query you have you should be getting an error: *You can't specify target table 'companys' for update in FROM clause*

One solution is to force MySQL to create a temporary result set that it can use as the source:

```
UPDATE companys 
   SET companys.signature = '$SIGNATURE' 
 WHERE companys.id = ( 
   SELECT id FROM (
     SELECT companys.id 
     FROM companys 
     JOIN users 
     ON users.company = companys.id 
     WHERE users.id = '$LOGGED_IN_USER'
   ) src
 );
```

See this [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed73) for a working example.